# ng-submit prevents default action - meaning?

Tags: angularjs

From the ng-book:

We use ng-submit to bind an expression to an onsubmit event. This directive also prevents the default action (sending the request and reloading the page), but only if the form does not contain an action attribute.

What is the meaning of the above paragraph?

Comment: It seems fairly self explanatory. What about it do you not understand?

Answer (score 1):

It means that :

```
<form ng-submit="submit()"></form>
```

Will prevent the submit event. And never post the form to your server.

**But**

```
<form ng-submit="$ctrl.submit()" action="/url" method="post"></form>
```

Will **not** prevent the default submit event.
If you do nothing, your form will be treat as a classic html form and post the result to /url on your server (after the submit code of your controller).

To prevent it in this case, you need to pass the event in submit this way :

```
<form ng-submit="$ctrl.submit($event)" action="/url" method="post"></form>
```

And in your controller :

```
function submit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- If `<form>` tag have both of these attribute: `<form ng-submit="submit()" action="http://example.com">` In that case it will call "submit()" method as well as it will also redirect to action link.
- But if it only has `ng-submit` and not having the action attribute : `<form ng-submit="submit()">` In that case there will no redirect on submission and it will only excute the `submit()` method.